# External sound card stops functioning after suspend

Tags: 12.04, sound, suspend, soundcard, external-soundcard

After reading:
[Re: Cannot suspend or hibernate Asus desktop ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132107)
I got the suspend working on a desktop. 
The only problem is that the external sound card that I have (Audiophile 2496) stops functioning. After suspend it is not even listed as an option in the sound settings. After restarting (killing) pulseaudio it appears again but does not seem to give any audio as an output.

I tried also to reload the module for the card (snd_ice1712) but I only get

```
ERROR: Module snd_ice1712 is in use
```

Forcing to remove the module only gives

```
ERROR: Removing 'snd_ice1712': Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to reload the sound card and get it up and working?

The release is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Try it a few times if it doesn't work